# Access filter's resulting object fields/properties/items oneliner in ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2

For example have following list of events:

```
    - id: 11
      message: "Something happened yet again."
    - id: 10
      message: "Oh no, Something happened again."
    - id: 8
      message: "Something happened."
```

I want to extract latest event id in one line/task. I haven't found the way to do so without using intermediate task for saving fist element of my list to variable. This solution seems bulky.

How can I separate field name from filter name? Is there any way to access field/property after 'first','last' filter. (Other filters that return dictionaries.)?

UPD:

Well, my question's phrasing was too confusing. I just needed id of latest event.
From Vladimir's answer:

```
    "{{ list|map(attribute='id')|max }}"
```

is quite enough in my case.

More so, as events already sorted by id(descending):

```
    "{{ list|first()['id] }}
```

will do.

So to separate filter name from field name in ansible all is needed is a pair of brackets after filter name (I guess because it's a python function after all).

Comment: What is the expected result? I'm not sure I understand what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: **"*id of the latest event*"**

A: The task

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ l|map(attribute='id')|max }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: '11'
```

---

In addition to this, the oneliner task

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ (l|items2dict(key_name='id', value_name='message'))[l|map(attribute='id')|max] }}"
```

gives the message of the latest id

```yaml
  msg: Something happened yet again.
```

Comment: Well, my question's phrasing was too confusing I guess.